# Server Sent Events error despite http 200

Tags: javascript, php

Hello I have next two files:
testsse.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<h1>Test of server sent events</h1>
<script>
    var eventSource = new EventSource("sse.php");
    eventSource.onmessage = function(event) {
    console.log("It works");
};
eventSource.onerror = function(error) {
console.error("eventSource failed: ", error);
};
</script>
```

And sse.php

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/event-stream\n\n");
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
echo "ssetest\n\n";
flush();
?>
```

So in console there are a lot of errors, and in the network tab a lot of pings, here the screenshots:
[image]
[image]

MDN says if response from server is 200, means all is ok, but in network tab you can clearly see there are response code 200, but still erorrs at console that are very big. Code is very small and easy so I dont even know what is causing problem. Also path to sse.php is correct (I hide it from screenshots with black boxes)

Comment: You don't need the trailing `\n\n` in the header. That's invalid HTTP.

Comment: @Dai still errors, at first time I made it without \n\n and when it showed me error I added

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do server-sent events initiate every 3 seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53888030/why-do-server-sent-events-initiate-every-3-seconds)

Comment: @Ivar it gives me errors at console, problem is not a lot of pings

Comment: @Vadim Did you read the (my own) accepted answer? You get errors because the connection is lost because your PHP closes the connection after the result is sent.

Comment: @Ivar It just gives me errors every seccond when I try that

Comment: When you try what @Vadim?

Comment: @Ivar when I put recconect after 1 second, I tried solution from question you sent me

Comment: That only shortens the time between retries. The real solution is implementing the PHP properly, as I mentioned in that answer. A good explanation can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events#sending_events_from_the_server).